# Accessibility Methodology for non-standard Table data

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

**Issue Description:**

> I am developing the UI for a list of advisor meetings. The list is formatted like a table, with a row of column headers and corresponding data. Each meeting contains a row of data as well as a description section below that row. Each meeting card is also expandable to show additional data. I am unsure of the best aria method to make this markup more accessible.

[Screenshot of the UI I'm developing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7snh6.gif) (actually a gif that shows the expand functionality)

**Goal:**

> To make it easier for screen readers to easily navigate the list of meetings

**Potential Solutions:**

> 1. Use aria attributes to construct a table for the elements that are in a table format (https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/table/table.html) I'm not sure how navigable this would be, especially when it comes to navigating to the description section or the collapsible details section...
>    2. Hide the table header from screen readers and make the meeting wrappers li elements so that it forms a list. I would add hidden screen reader labels to each of the unlabeled values. My concern is that the entire meeting is too much content for a li element and I'm not sure what the navigability for screen readers would be like.

Answer (score 0):

From my own research for work, I have come up with the following pointers:

- use the most specific and accurate html tag, and use css to style it the way you want (no need to make a button out of a span, a button's default styles can be overwritten)
- use case as much as possible to reduce unnecessarily nested html
- aria attributes are great, but should be a last resort.

In the case of your table, I would say use the standard html table elements, just make sure to use the correct tags, like `th`, and make sure to include a description or label at the top of the table. Screen readers should know what to do with a table. If a table is the most accurate description of what you're building, use that :) Just be sure to use it in a standard and predictable way, and (see how often I say this) use only css for your styling.

For the meetings there is an element for that: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/html5-details-tag/amp/ you can style it any way you want, but I think the arrow is chosen by the browser. But a screen readers will read the summary and give the user the option to open it. I think yours is a great use case for this element.

I wouldn't hide content like headers from screen readers. People who use assistive technologies are used to navigating with them and headers are informative content.

Answer (score 0):

**Tables for Structure**

I would recommend staying away from tables, but that's my personal preference. You *could* make this accessible using tables, but it would end up being more complicated than it needs to be.

**List Structure**

The list structure that you described would be fine, but ultimately you *could* convey the hierarchical structure of what you're doing here by using only headings and paragraphs.

**Off-the-Shelf Solutions**

Many of the popular frontend frameworks (like Bootstrap, Material, etc.) have already solved the problem of accessible [accordions](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/), [collapse elements](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/), [expansion panels](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview), or whatever else you want to call it. Unless you're a strong JS developer, I would recommend starting with a pre-made solution from a well known framework and then testing using a [decent screen reader](https://www.nvaccess.org/download/).

**Custom Solutions**

There's nothing wrong with implementing your own solution, assuming you have the skillset and time available to do so.

W3C has some great guidance on the desired behavior of [accessible accordion elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.2/examples/accordion/accordion.html), and the A11Y project has a nice [design pattern library](https://a11yproject.com/patterns/#accordions-and-tabs) with usable code samples.

For the ARIA markup, you'll need to make use of `aria-expanded`, `aria-controls` and `aria-labelledby` respectively. Depending on how your screen reader tests go, you may also wish to set focus when the expandable element opens.